# Cancer Drugs that Interfere with Glucose Uptake

Tags: cancer

I have been reading about certain compounds that inhibit tumor development by means of interfering with GLUT1 transporters. (Eg: https://www.caymanchem.com/pdfs/19900.pdf)

I was wondering if there exists any medicine approved for human use that relies (entirely or in part) or a similar approach?